# Shrink vertical space eqnarray

Tags: spacing, eqnarray

How to globally shrink the vertical space between lines in `eqnarray`? I understand `eqnarray` is not preferable but it is a legacy file for reprint.

```
\begin{eqnarray}
1 + 1 &=& 2 \\
1 + 1 &=& 2 
\end{eqnarray}
```

It is possible to shrink using `\\[-.5ex]` but is there a global way?

Comment: The standard spacing is quite narrow, I'm not sure what the problem is. Can you please add a minimal example? Are you perhaps generally increasing the interline spacing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the value of `\jot`.

```
\setlength{\jot}{0pt}
\begin{eqnarray}
    1 + 1 &=& 2 \\
    1 + 1 &=& 2 
\end{eqnarray}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! \jot is the key.

Answer (score 1):

It is possibile also to use the enviroment *spreadlines* of the package `mathtools`. I have set `0em` as a null space.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{spreadlines}{0em} 
\begin{eqnarray}
    1 + 1 &=& 2 \\
    1 + 1 &=& 2 
\end{eqnarray}
\end{spreadlines}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here there is an example with a negative measure `-.3em` (it is more shrink).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{spreadlines}{-.3em} 
\begin{eqnarray}
    1 + 1 &=& 2 \\
    1 + 1 &=& 2 
\end{eqnarray}
\end{spreadlines}
\end{document}
```

[image]